# PHP- downloading 60mb file from ftp - 500: Internal server error

Tags: php

**I have written following php code which should connect to a FTP, goto a folder and download a 60MB file on regular intervals. When i try to run the code it throws a 500 error, is it a problem `with server_file`**

```
<?
// define some variables
$local_file = 'abc.zip';
$server_file = '/ftproot/abc/abc.zip';
$ftp_server="ftp.abc.biz";
$ftp_user_name="abc";
$ftp_user_pass="mypasssword";

$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// try to download $server_file and save to $local_file
if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
    echo "Successfully written to $local_file\n";
}
else {
    echo "There was a problem\n";
}
// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);


?>
```

**500: Internal server error**

This error is generated when a script running on the server could not be implemented or permissions are incorrectly assigned for files or directories

Troubleshooting suggestions:

Temporarily disable any rewrite rules by renaming your .htaccess file if it exists.

Ensure that any CGI or Perl scripts have at least .755. permissions.

If trying to run PHP and you get this error, you may have an invalid php.ini in your /cgi-bin, or may be missing your php.dat file in this folder.

**.HTACCESS FILE**

```
Options -Indexes
```

FTP View

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's the error logged?

Comment: @AlessandroNiciforo i do not see any error log on ftp

Comment: @AlessandroNiciforo my fto folder structure screenshots http://prntscr.com/aivigr

http://prntscr.com/aivipf

Comment: No, your error_log on the server with the PHP on it. What is the error logged in there?

Comment: i do not see any error_log on the server

Comment: Check webserver logfiles. HTTP 500 is a general server error.